# Excel: Removing Duplicate Values Using Array Formula For Multiple Columns

Tags: arrays, excel, duplicates, multiple-columns

I am trying to remove the duplicates from 7 different columns and combine the unique values into one column and I can't find a way to do that using an Excel formula

I've tried the array approach below, but it doesn't work for for more than one column:

```
=INDEX($A$11:$A$100000, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$11:C11,$A$11:$A$100000), 0))
```

Here's what I'd like ideally:

Starting data:

Column 1: `a  b  d  c  b  i`

Column 2: `c  g  h  f  d  c`

Column 3: `f  e  a  g  b  a`

Ending result:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
...
```

(order not important)

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this answers the question exactly, but you could try using COUNTIFS to identify rows where combinations of two or more columns contain duplicate values:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)
```

This formula will return the number of rows where the value in B1 and C1 is duplicated. You can copy and paste it down to every row in your formula, or use it as an array formula.

There's more on how to do this here:

http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/find-duplicate-rows-excel-across-multiple-columns